# Solving a constrained convex optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function with the following form:

```
P0 = 1 / Sum[(lambda^i)/((mu^i)*i!), {i, 0, B1}] 
P = N[P0*lambda^B1/(mu^B1*B1!)]
```

Where **mu** and **lambda** are fixed parameters and **B1** is unknown.

The code refers to a Markov chain process that I am calculating.

[image]

And I need to find the minimum integer value of **B1** that corresponds to the constraint **P(B1) <= 0.05**

Since I am new to the Mathematica, I find it a bit hard to use a correct function. Could you please point me to a correct way of solving such a problem with Mathematica?

Thank you.

**UPD**

@ulrich-neumann provided a better way to define the function:

`F[mu_, lambda_] := (E^(-(lambda/mu)) lambda^B1 mu^-B1 Gamma[1 + B1])/(B1! Gamma[1 + B1, lambda/mu])`

And @akku14 has built on top of the previous commentaries to define B1's boundaries:

`NMinimize[{(F[1/3, 8] - .05)^2, F[1/3, 8] <= 0.05, B1 > 1,    Element[B1, Integers]}, {B1, 5, 50}]`  to get `{0.0000976008, {B1 -> 30}}`

Comment: `Ceiling[x /. FindRoot[f[x] == 0.05, {x, 100}]]`

Comment: Please post the code about such function.

Comment: @cvgmt it is a simple Markov chain calculation, I want Pb not to exceed 0.05 and find a suitable B1 parameter 


P0 = 1 / Sum[(lambda^i)/((mu^i)*i!), {i, 0, B1}]

P = N[P0*lambda^B1/(mu^B1*B1!)]

Answer (score 1):

First define your function depending on `mu,lambda`

```
F[mu_, lambda_] := (E^(-(lambda/mu)) lambda^B1 mu^-B1 Gamma[1 + B1])/(B1! Gamma[1 + B1, lambda/mu])
```

Now it's possible to minimize for given parameters (examplary `mu=1/3,lambda=8`)

```
NMinimize[{B1, F[ 1/3, 8 ] <= 0.05, B1 > 0,Element[B1, Integers]}, B1 ]
(*{3., {B1 -> 3}}*)
```

This result seems to be wrong (Thanks @cvgmt`s  comment)! Without the integer constraint NMinimize evaluates

```
NMinimize[{B1, F[ 1/3, 8 ] <= 0.05, B1 > 0 }, B1 ]
(* B1->29.172 *)
```

The correct solution follows to `B1=30` !

Comment: Test the example  `F[1/3, 8]` . The result should be `31` or `30`

Comment: @cvgmt Something wents wrong with the integerconstraint! Without my attempt gives `B1->29.172`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thank you for the logic of solving. For some reasons I can't copy and paste your solution for a quick test, I get the following error:

`NMinimize
:NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints`

And `{1.,{B1->1}} `

Comment: Try the last version (without integer constraint) `NMinimize[{B1, F[ 1/3, 8 ] <= 0.05, B1 > 0,Element[B1, Integers]}, B1 ]
(* B1->29.172 *)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I feel super dumb at this moment, but there is literally zero difference in formulas between the first and the second one. Should I also include comments? If so, it does not work as well. What am I missing here? Should I pre-define something else?

Comment: Sorry may fault, I modified the answer!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann , supply starting values for B1 and minimize quadratic difference, not  B1.  `NMinimize[{(F[1/3, 8] - .05)^2, F[1/3, 8] <= 0.05, B1 > 1, 
  Element[B1, Integers]}, {B1, 5, 50}] `  to get `{0.0000976008, {B1 -> 30}} ` .

Comment: @Akku14 wow thank you, this works like a charm. Thanks everyone for the insights and your help on this task, this gave me a lot of progress in terms of Mathematica thinking, but in order to minimize the frequency of such supposedly obvious questions I am going to take a full course on using Mathematica.

Comment: @Akku14 But how to get result for `F[1/20,8]`,`F[1/30,8]` or other `mu`?  I think set the range `{B1, 5, 50}` by hand is not the good way.

Comment: @cvgmt , Anyway it is always a good practice to have a look at the function in advance.  `Plot[{.05, F[1/30, 8]}, {B1, 5, 300}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[1, 300, 5], Automatic}] `

Comment: @Akku14  We need to find automatic method to do this instead of `Table[F[1/30, 8] // N, {B1, 5, 300}]`

Comment: @akku14 Thanks for your idea. I didn't know that `NMinimize` allows to prescribe an interval in the form `{B1,5,50}`! Where did you find it?